# Website font breaks accented Greek text

Tags: support, status-review, fonts, design

The font stack on this website breaks ordinary accented Greek, such that you would see on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_1:1#Source_text_and_translations) or [Greek Bible websites](https://www.academic-bible.com/en/online-bibles/novum-testamentum-graece-na-28/read-the-bible-text/):

> Ἐν ἀρχῇ ἦν ὁ λόγος, καὶ ὁ λόγος ἦν πρὸς τὸν θεόν, καὶ θεὸς ἦν ὁ λόγος.

> Βίβλος γενέσεως Ἰησοῦ Χριστοῦ υἱοῦ Δαυὶδ υἱοῦ Ἀβραάμ.

(And as a screenshot)

[image: Screenshot of the above text]

Please change the fonts so that the accents are displayed correctly.

Fonts covering the Latin, Greek, and Hebrew alphabets well are rare. One good option remains Cardo:

- http://scholarsfonts.net/cardofnt.html
- https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Cardo/glyphs

Comment: Since this would have to be a global SE modification, perhaps it would better belong on the main SE Meta site? If you do start a proposal there you could leave a link here for us to upvote?

Comment: @Stevecanhelp It doesn't have to be a global SE modification - Christianity already has a different main font (Palatino).

Comment: would a font change definitely be enough to enable all the extra Unicode characters needed for accented Greek plus Hebrew? Maybe so, but worth checking.

Comment: @Stevecanhelp Well browsers are clever and will find a substitute font for unicode characters that aren't included in the main font. The issue here is that our site's font (Georgia) does support the accents, it just displays them incorrectly.

Comment: Why do I see them correctly? No problem in font

Comment: @Michael16 Probably using a browser that doesn't have Georgia. It's fine on my Android phone for example.

Comment: That's not true. Georgia has no problem with Greek. I read ebooks in Georgia. He must have some another error from his side

Comment: I use firefox and opera. There is no problem. You can use dark reader extension, it has the feature of changing fonts for selected sites.

Comment: @Michael16 Maybe it's just Chrome's version of Georgia then. In any case it's broken in one of the most common browsers.

Comment: Has there been any updating to this stack?  I'm growing somewhat annoyed that, when I have to write/copy minuscule Greek, if there's an accent or breathing mark, it squishes the letter below the height of the rest of the letters.  It seems like the "latin" section solved this by going all sans serif.

Comment: As the OP listed, Cardo seems like a decent stop-gap measure. Tinos might be another short-term choice:  https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Tinos